# Use of weights in Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

In Dijkstra algorithm, what is the use of weights(distance measures) preassigned to edges? Why cant we just update the distances of vertices by using path length data structure? I think it is redundant and sometimes increases the time complexity. Say suppose we have a graph like one vertex adjacent to two neighbours with distance on the corresponding edges to be say $9$ and $10$. Then, though path length is same $1$, the distance assigned to the two adjacent vertices after the first step would be $9$ and $10$ even though the path lengths are same. Isn't it? Any clarifications? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Weights can be used to encode some important information, such as cost or time to travel between two vertices. Dijkstra's algorithm can be used to find "shortest" path where shortest means *smallest total weight*. For example, the edges' weights may represent the time it would take for a car to travel that edge (the vertices could represent locations), and Dijkstra's algorithm would essentially find you a "minimal time" path. Of course, if you're just interested in finding a shortest path in terms of least number of edges, you could assign weight $1$ to every edge.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth so then, it is a MST(minimum spanning tree) algorithm, with the difference that the tree is a path, right?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm generally will not give you a MST. Instead, it is used to give you a *shortest path from a given source vertex* to any other vertex. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909281/use-dijkstras-to-find-a-minimum-spanning-tree.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth But if I run the algorithm over all vertices, would it not give me a spanning path?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm can be used to give you a spanning tree, but it won't generally yield a *minimum* spanning tree. You can have a look at **Prim's algorithm** though. See e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144279/difference-between-prims-and-dijkstras-algorithms).